# Bounded functions are linear combinations of functions of absolute value one.

Tags: analysis

Is it true that any complex-valued bounded measurable function on a measurable space is a finite linear combination of functions of absolute value one? If true, how is this statement proved?

Comment: Do you mean a limit of such functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a complex number $w$ such that $0<|w|\le 1$, let $\theta = \cos^{-1} \frac{1+|w|}{2} \in [0,\pi/2)$ and define
$$\psi_1(w) = \frac{w}{|w|}e^{i\theta},\quad \psi_2(w) = \frac{w}{|w|}e^{-i\theta},\quad \psi_3(w) = -\frac{w}{|w|} $$
Observe that $\psi_1, \psi_2,\psi_3$ are continuous on the punctured disk  $0<|w|\le 1$, have modulus $1$, and satisfy
$$\psi_1(w) + \psi_2(w) +\psi_3(w) = w \tag{1}$$
Extend their definitions by $\psi_1(0)=e^{\pi i/3}$, $\psi_2(0)=e^{-\pi i/3}$, $\psi_3(0)=-1$. The extension is not continuous, but the other properties still hold.

Given a measurable function $f$ such that $|f|\le 1$ pointwise, let $g_k=\psi_k\circ f$ for $k=1,2,3$. By (1) we have 
$g_1+g_2+g_3=f$. On the set where $f=0$, the functions $g_k$ are constant. On the set where $f\ne 0$, they are measurable, being the composition of a  continuous function with a measurable function.

For a general bounded function, you can either scale (since you allow coefficients in linear combination), or write it as a sum of functions bounded by $1$, e.g., $f=f/N+\dots+f/N$. With the second approach you represent $f$ as a *sum* of unimodular functions, not just a linear combination.